# Find the limit of $\sqrt[9]{5x^2 + 1} / \sqrt[7]{4x^3 - 1}$ as $x \to \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

I don't know how to rewrite this expression to find this limit.  I did consider l'Hospital, but computing derivatives does not eliminate the radicals, so I don't think this is the way to go.

My intuition says that this limit is zero because the denominator grows faster --- we're comparing the power 1/9 with the power 1/7 and 1/7 > 1/9.  Even though I think my intuition could not be used without a lot of care, I think it is warranted in this situation because the expression under the power 1/7 is actually faster than the expression under the power 1/9.  Therefore, I have here all the reasons to say that the denominator grows faster than the numerator.  (So I might be lucky enough in the current situation.)

I'd like to find an elementary way to rewrite it, if there is a way.  Thank you.

Comment: For these types of problems, you want to divide numerator and denominator by smallest exponent of $x$.  So, divide num and denom by $x^{2/9}$.

Comment: A minor correction, we're not comparing $1/7$ and $1/9$, rather we're comparing $2/9$ and $3/7$ because the power of $x$ also matters.

Comment: Same as $$\sqrt[63]{\frac{(5x^2+1)^7}{(4x^3-1)^9}}$$

Comment: That's what I'm looking for.  I had not seen these facts yet.  @Doug, when you say smallest exponent of $x$ you mean the power of the polynomial inside the radical combined with the power of the radical, so the numerator yields 2/9, which is smaller than 3/7.  Okay, I see that now.

Comment: @Anvit, my question does say that the power of $x$ in the polynomials does matter.  I did not ignore them.

Comment: It might also help to rewrite it in terms of $y\to0^+$, letting $x=1/y$.

Comment: I like the version above with a fraction inside the 63rd root - this makes it very clear and easy to finish, and suggests formally dividing by $x^{14}$ - which I came up with similarly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to apply  inequalities. For $x\ge 1$ we have
$$0\le  {\sqrt[9]{5x^2+1}\over \sqrt[7]{4x^3-1}}\le {\sqrt[9]{5x^2+x^2}\over \sqrt[7]{4x^3-x^3}} =6^{1/9}3^{-1/7}x^{{2\over 9}-{3\over 7}}$$ As the exponent of $x$ is negative by squeezing rule we get $0$ as the limit.

Comment: @mr_e_man Right. Thanks.

Comment: That's actually pretty easy to read.  Thank you.  It's a pretty clear argument because you did not lose any constant inside the radical and the inequalities are very easily built (and it's also pretty short).  Very well done.

Comment: I am glad you like the answer.

Comment: Clever answer, I should've thought of that. +1

Answer (score 3):

$5x^2+1\sim 5x^2$ and $4x^3-1\sim 4x^3$. So the limit is equivalent to $$\frac{5^{1/9}}{4^{1/7}}\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x^{2/9}}{x^{3/7}}=\frac{5^{1/9}}{4^{1/7}}\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x^{-13/63}$$Which is zero as you suspected.

Comment: That's pretty elegant, but it seems like an answer given from mathematician to mathematician.  Totally valid.  I'm going to select @JoseCarlosSantos, however, because his is more elementary, even though I can't follow it.  That's the funny thing --- I can follow your answer and not his.  I need to figure out the algebra jumps with my short legs.  Thank you very much for your very elegant solution.  It is my favorite here for sure.

Comment: @user1145880 Big O notation is basically saying the quickest-growing term in a function. We could also remove extra coefficients. In this case, the quickest growing term in $5x^2+1$ is $5x^2$, and the quickest growing part of $5x^2$ is $x^2$.

Comment: I agree.  I'm essentially using it in my argument in the question.  Perhaps @JoseCarlosSantos is also essentially using it.  (I'm not sure.)  (If he is losing that $-1$ inside the 1/7-radical, for instance, then I think that's indeed a use of big-o notation.  That's effectively saying --- these constants don't matter when $x$ is large.)

Comment: This answer would be correct (and would be my favorite one, as a short version of @JoséCarlosSantos's) if $O$ was replaced with $\sim$ (and if the coefficients were not forgotten). Mainly: you cannot derive the "equivalent" limit from your $O$'s. $4x^3-1=O(x^3)$ means that $(4x^3-1)/x^3$ is bounded. This is true but not sufficient.  $x^3=O(4x^3-1)$ would be more useful.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for your comment. I will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You have$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[9]{5x^2+1}}{\sqrt[7]{4x^3-1}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\dfrac{\sqrt[9]{5x^2+1}}{x^{3/7}}}{\dfrac{\sqrt[7]{4x^3-1}}{x^{3/7}}}.\label{a}\tag1$$But$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt[7]{4x^3-1}}{x^{3/7}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt[7]{4-x^{-3}}=\sqrt[7]4,$$whereas\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt[9]{5x^2+1}}{x^{3/7}}&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt[9]{5x^2+1}}{x^{2/9}}\cdot\frac1{x^{13/63}}\\&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt[9]{5+x^{-2}}\cdot\frac1{x^{13/63}}\\&=0,\end{align}and therefore \eqref{a} is equal to $0$.

Comment: It's amazing how you type your answer --- you just typed all the necessary symbols with no spaces at all.  Very unreadable code for sure.  But surely most people will only read your presentation and perhaps that's all you and I should care too.  Your algebra tricks are amazing and your answer is my pick because it seems more elementary than @KamalSaleh, which is more appropriate to this type of question.  But I have trouble reading your algebra steps.  Let me ask you to elaborate on one point --- in the next comment.  Thanks!

Comment: I believe you are using more than just plain algebra when you say $\lim (4x^3 -1)^{1/7}/x^{3/7} = \lim (4 - x^{-3})$.  Maybe you're using some Calculus?  I can't see your reasoning in that step.  For instance, $(4x^3 -1)^{1/7}/x^{3/7} = (4x^3 -1)^{1/7} x^{-3/7}$ for sure, but unless I ignore that $-1$, I don't know how to bring that $x^{-3/7}$ inside the radical.  Can you help?  Thank you!

Comment: What I am doing is\begin{align}\frac{\sqrt[7]{4x^3-1}}{x^{3/7}}&=\frac{\sqrt[7]{4x^3-1}}{\sqrt[7]{x^3}}\\&=\sqrt[7]{\frac{4x^3-1}{x^3}}\\&=\sqrt[7]{4-x^{-3}}.\end{align}So, yes, I am only using plain algebra.

Comment: Wow!  Very nice.  Thank you for showing it.  I had not seen it.  That's indeed just plain algebra.  And that makes your solution pretty and algebraic, two great compliments!  But because I can only pick one answer, I'll stick with @RyszardSzwarc.  (Perhaps you'd agree with me that his solution is neat too.)